# search same file in subdirectories and replace string in all of them

Tags: linux, shell, replace, sed, find

hi am a total noob in shell scripting,
i want to make a findandfix.sh to search for a all files called file.xml inside a all directories inside FOLDER1 and replace a a specific line in all them that begin with `<linex=`  with  `<activate=option1,option2`

```
  FOLDER1
      |
      |---->FOLDER2
      |           |->file.xml
      |
      |---->FOLDER3
      |           |->file.xml
      |
      |---->FOLDER4
      |           |->file.xml
      |
      |---->FOLDER5
                  |->file.xml
```

i think it will require using `find` and `sed` but i don't know how to put them together to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you well :

```
find /system/home/user/folder1 -name 'file.xml' -exec sed -i 's@linex=@activate=option1,option2@' {} \;
```

Make a backup before test, or remove the `-i` switch

Comment: like  "/system/home/user/folder1"

Comment: thanks , does the @ stand for the < thant was in the line i wand to edit or it must be added?

Comment: The `@` is a delimiter

Comment: HI IT WORKED PERFECTLY BUT WHEN TRAYING ON OTHER COMPLEX EXEMPLE IT REPLACE PART OF THE LINE IN LEFT PART OF THE OLD ONE

Comment: Why did you CRYYY ?

Comment: the line am using on it is : <string options="1g,2g,3g,4g,5g,6g,7g,8g,9g"/>

Comment: i want to rplace it with i shoter one <string options="1g,2g,3g"/>  but it give me this instead  :  <string options=1g,2g,3g"/>"1g,2g,3g,4g,5g,6g,7g,8g,9g"/>  and it forget the " after the =